# Remote image size in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I try to display a multiple image (with different size) inside a tableview cell.. The problem is, the UIImageView (`postImage`) is in a default size while the image is still downloading. What I want is the UIImageView (`postImage`) to show the exact height & width for the downloading image (like a place holder for the downloading image).

```
let postImageURL = posts.photoStdUrl

    cell.request?.cancel()

    if let image = self.postImageCache.objectForKey(postImageURL) as? UIImage {
        cell.postPhoto.image = image
    } else {

        cell.postPhoto.image = nil

        cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, postImageURL).validate(contentType: ["image/*"]).responseImage() {
            (request, _, image, error) in
            if error == nil && image != nil {

                self.postImageCache.setObject(image!, forKey: request.URLString)

                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

                cell.postPhoto.image = image
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you solved this issue?? I'm also facing the same issue.. how can i solve it?

Comment: i follow @Vonfry suggestion. Write a code in server side to get the image size (after the image been uploaded to server). Then each time app request, server will send the image size in response.

Comment: My Problem is "I need to show exact image, if it is smaller/larger than phone width need to resize to aspect ratio" , at the end i need to show exact image there will be no cropping .. how can i acheive that. [Github](https://github.com/akshaypakanati/SelfSizingCellTest) you can find a sample here.. please suggest me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/size

You can see this link. After you downloads the data and save it into a UIImage object, you can call `image.size` to get the image size which return a CGSize object.

Comment: can i get the height and width for the image before we download the image. Reason: i need to prepare the placeholder for the image. - thanks in advance

Comment: @Jamal If you want to get it before download, you must write it by youselef on server. I mean you can use get method which is writen by youself on server to get size before downloading. I think iOS can not do it.